# Calculator issue

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm doing a calculator app and I have one problem. I can not distinguish negative numbers and subtraction. I use this code to set all numbers apart.

```
ArrayList<Double> doubles;
String[] strings1 = string.split("\\*");
for (String string2 : strings1) {
    String[] string3 = string2.split("÷");
    for (String string4 : string3) {
        String[] string5 = string4.split("\\+");
        for (String string6 : string5) {
            Log.e("Point_1", "String5 " + string5.toString());
            Log.e("Point_1", "String6 " + string6);
            String[] string7 = string6.split("\\-");
            for (String string8 : string7) {
                doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(string8));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get is `[number1,number2,number3 ...]`(they all are positive) and in another `ArrayList` operators like `[+,-,+,*,- ...]`. What I need is to put in first `ArrayList(doubles)` all numbers but make them negative if they are. Let me give you an example. If we have a string like "`-3+6`" then in doubles should be numbers: `-3;6` and in the second `ArrayList` only "`+`". And vise versa if we have "`6-3`" then in doubles we should have: `6;3` and in second `ArrayList` only "`-`".
How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up the shunting yard algorithm. Don't remove your operators.

Comment: I'd make a POJO that allows me to store an operator and a value privately

Comment: Aside: in your log statement, rather than `string5.toString()` you want `Arrays.toString(string5)`.

Comment: Basically, if `string8` is an empty string, you may assume it comes from before a leading minus and hence negate the following item from `string7`.

Comment: @ole-v-v Thanks. So, after I split my statement and put everything in an array I can start a new loop and everything that has an index of 1 or more is gonna be with minus, right?

Comment: looks like a very ad-hoc method. What about using a recursive descent parser (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)? That would also make it easy to correctly handle operator precedence (* and / before + and -).

Comment: I agree with @Henry, it’s a minimal change to the code in the question and doesn’t address any other issues one might find there.

Comment: If it’s a requirement that operator precedence is respected, you will probably want to look into the shunting yard algorithm (as @cricket_007 said) or a recursive descent parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `string8` is an empty string, you may assume it comes from before a leading minus. Replace your innermost for loop with:

```
                int index = 0;
                while (index < string7.length) {
                    String string8 = string7[index];
                    if (string8.isEmpty()) { // assume there was a leading minus here
                        // reverse sign of next double
                        index++;
                        doubles.add(-Double.parseDouble(string7[index]));
                    } else {
                        doubles.add(Double.parseDouble(string8));
                    }
                    index++;
                }
```

With this change, given the string `-3+6` the code gives `[-3.0, 6.0]`. With `6-3`, `[6.0, 3.0]` (which is correct because the minus denotes subtraction, not a negative number).

This doesn’t take multiple leading minuses into account, say `--3+6`. If you wanted to, all you would have to do was to detect multiple empty strings in a row and see if there was an even or an odd number of them.